# Rails API hide certain attributes from return

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example I want to hide **id** in my json responses.

I found I can do: `@user.posts.map{|p| p.attributes.except("id")}` but it's a bit long and clunky.

I'd like to formalize it so when we're passing back posts to the frontend we aren't accidentally exposing the **id**.

Comment: How are you constructing your API? Are you using a framework like `grape`? Are you using Serializers of some kind? Are you just rendering JSON? Please add details because while we cannot specifically help without further detail, I can tell you almost certainly, just based on the content of this post, that this is not the best or most appropriate way to manage this. Also you might want to elucidate on why you don't want to pass the id as this seems like a very odd request and might make it difficult to build out relational parts of your system.

Comment: The data is a contrived example, but imagine I have an endpoint used for display purposes on the frontend and I'm doing `format.json { render json: @user.posts }`